# how to segue to storyboard viewcontroller from xib view with swift 3

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue, xib

I'm having the hardest time finding an answer for this.

I have a xib view  that is within a scrollview that is within a view controller. In the xib I have a button with an action and I need to segue to a view controller I have in my storyboard. I also would like to be able to use a custom segue.

So far, I have read that I can instantiate the viewcontroller from the storyboard to segue to it. But then I don't know how to present that controller.

thanks for any help...

UPDATE:

this is the code I'm using to perform the segue.

In parent ViewController:

```
    static var referenceVC: UIViewController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewdidload")
    LevelSelectViewController.referenceVC = self

    setupScrollView()
}
```

code in xib view file

```
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sightWordController")

        let parent = LevelSelectViewController.referenceVC!

        let segue = InFromRightCustomSegue(identifier: "test", source: parent, destination: vc)


        segue.perform()
```

Comment: Segues are typically confined to storyboard usage only. You'll likely have to add your view (which you can configure the whole class of the view to load from a nib) into the storyboard in some way and then you can hook a segue up to it. Otherwise, they are called `UIStoryboardSegue`s for a reason.

Comment: If you use a custom segue that can be allocated in code, you just need a VC to perform on I believe, which means you can climb the responder chain to find the associated VC to perform it on. In general though, it sounds like you want a custom transition and some sort of delegate callbacks. There's absolutely no reason to make your code this complicated to keep a segue.

Comment: I just got it to work. my biggest issue was getting a reference to the parent viewcontroller so that I can call the segue. The way I got the reference is a bit of a hack, I just made a static reference variable in the parent view controller that I could use within the xib file. Is there a better way to get the reference? I will update the question to show my code.

Comment: if you want the reference to be generic (such as a regular segue is) just climb the responder chain to see which VC wants to handle/can handle presenting or performing the segue first.

Comment: If you want/need to be less generic, you can also use delegation to inform the VC that an action has occurred and it should respond.

Comment: and example can be seen in the attached answer below

Comment: I'm relatively new to iOS programming. I'm not sure what you mean by responder chain, or how I would do that. I saw other answers to similar questions about delegation. but again, I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: The answer I've added can get you started. Note documentation on the responder chain is attached as well

Comment: Being new to iOS programming, as a few notes to consider, avoid singletons at all costs if possible, and try to name your references robustly. `referenceVC` is a summarized/abbreviated name, the swift API guidelines will also speak against that.

Comment: I've also referenced the core competency documentation for delegation and target-action events in the answer below. You definitely should take some time out to understand these design patterns as iOS development is built upon them.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, Segues are typically confined to storyboard usage as noted in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html). You can implement a custom xib view in a storyboard via `@IBDesignable` like approaches and have you're view load from the xib into the storyboard file/class. This way, you gain the benefits of both worlds. Otherwise, you may want to approach this in another fashion (such as [delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)/[target-action](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) events, etc).

You may also climb the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) and call a segue related to the VC loaded from the storyboard (the segue doesn't necessarily have to be attached to any particular action) via getting a reference to the VC and calling the segue. You can climb the responder chain in a manner such as the example code below:

```
protocol ChildViewControllerContainer {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? { get }
}


protocol ViewControllerTraversable {
    func viewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T?
}

extension UIView: ViewControllerTraversable {

    func viewController<T: UIViewController>() -> T? {
        var responder = next

        while let currentResponder = responder {
            guard responder is T else {
                responder = currentResponder.next
                continue
            }

            break
        }

        return responder as? T
    }
}

extension UITableViewCell: ChildViewControllerContainer {
    weak var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        return viewController() as UIViewController?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into this. It definitely looks over my head right now. Do you see any issues with the way that I did it? I edited my question to include the code that I used to get it to work

Comment: You definitely should not be referencing a static variable the way you are to reference the parent VC. That issue is solved by the code above.

Comment: Is there anyway you can include comments to your code to help me better understand what is happening?

Comment: I'd rather encourage you to run through the code and step through it. Just add this code to your custom view file, then call myCustomView.viewController as UIViewController

Comment: Okay I'll do that. thanks for the code. I will let you know if I run into issues.